# Changing Keyboard Language - Selenium

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, katalon-studio

I'm trying to change the keyboard language from english to russion because my team decided to prevent user type on a textbox before he changes the language to russian. I'm trying to test this feature using katalon and Selenium but I'm not able to change the keyboard inputs language to russian.

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating a web driver instance, you can set the preferred language option. For Chrome, it looks like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments(“–lang=ru”);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```